# How do I re-run?

Tags: pascal

I am making a program, but I want after the user inputing the value and showing the result, I make a choice to user if he wants to repeat the program again. How do you make that? I usually rerun it by ctrl+f9 (run again after closing the program) but that's inefficient right?

Comment: You can easily put your code in a `repeat...until` loop so that it repeats until some condition is met, f.i. the user inputs an empty value.

Comment: Mentioning compiler , operating system and other details might be useful too.

Comment: In addition to what @MartynA has said, breaking out the code that needs to run repeatedly into a function/procedure will likely help.